# How to get text inside nested span using Selenium (Python)?

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver

How to get all texts with class `jss160`:

```
<div class="jss157 red">
  <img class="jss158" src="/static/media/e18d9.png" alt="Izimu">
    <span style="margin: 0px 3px; font-size: 10px;">:</span>
      <span>
        <span>
          <span class="jss159">ご質問</span>

          <span class="jss160">質問</span>
        </span>
        <span>
          <span class="jss159">答え</span>
          <span class="jss160 answer">絶対に。</span>
        </span>
</span>
</div>
```

My goal is to get all texts inside `jss160` class. for this code my output is `質問`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Selenium you could do the following:

```py
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("span.jss160").text
```

To understand this better, try to play with the CSS selector, for example with simple code like this with `lxml.html` and `cssselect` installed:

```py
import lxml.html

tree = lxml.html.fromstring("""<div class="jss157 red">
  <img class="jss158" src="/static/media/e18d9.png" alt="Izimu">
    <span style="margin: 0px 3px; font-size: 10px;">:</span>
      <span>
        <span>
          <span class="jss159">ご質問</span>

          <span class="jss160">質問</span>
        </span>
        <span>
          <span class="jss159">答え</span>
          <span class="jss160 answer">絶対に。</span>
        </span>
</span>
</div>""")
tree.cssselect("span[class='jss160']")[0].text
# '質問'
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, You are using selenium webdriver

You can get elements with class jss160 using

```
element = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("jss160");
```

and get text using

```
element.text
```